# How to stop background ssh tunnel automatically along with session?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

What I want is like following:

1. I could setup a ssh tunnel at background on a Linux machine(Actually, I'd like to setup it in my .bashrc)
2. I could run process using this tunnel as any user on this machine at any time, only if the ssh tunnel process is active.
3. When I quit from the terminal/session, the ssh tunnel should also quit as well.

I know I could establish a background ssh tunnel in Linux as following:

`ssh -Nf -L 8000:1.2.3.4:8000 username@2.3.4.5`

While at the time I exit from this terminal/session, this ssh tunnel would still run at background.

How to make it also quit automitically?

Please note: 
This http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/11/24/auto-closing-ssh-tunnels/ doesn't meet my requirement. Because it requires me to launch my process right after the ssh tunnel process, and if my first task with ssh tunnel finished, I need setup the ssh tunnel again for a second task. 
On the other hand, if I set a long sleep time, then the ssh tunnel will not quit with my terminal.

Answer (score 2):

There is a clever solution here:

http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/11/24/auto-closing-ssh-tunnels/

The command they use is

```
ssh -f -L 25901:127.0.0.1:5901 me@remote.example.org sleep 10
vncviewer 127.0.0.1:25901:1
```

They feed the `sleep` command to the remote server first. They specify an arbitrarily short time (10 seconds). Since this was the "goal" of the connection, the tunnel would shut down automatically. It does not shutdown, though, because in that time the other command (in their case `vncserver`) accessed it. When the vncserver ends, the tunnel should auto-close.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! 
But I have to say this doesn't meet my requirement. Please check my update of question for the reaseon.